# How to start for SDN and open flow using Opendaylight controller

Tags: sdn, openflow, opendaylight

Is there any tutorials where I can start with SDN and OpenFlow using Opendaylight controller?

Tutorial should tell about the setting up of complete flow  from scratch .

-Ajay

Comment: you will get all the answers in these websites sdnhub.com and sdntutorials.com.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenDaylight Application Developer’s tutorial - SDN Hub](http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/opendaylight/) is a beginner level tutorial explaining about ODL from scratch.

Also [ODL - Getting Started Guide](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-boron/getting-started-guide/index.html) is a good place to get familiar with ODL concepts and terminology.